# Ginseng supplement recommendation

Tags: supplements

I have tried many different ginseng supplements for increased energy and focus and the main problem with all of them was side effects related with going to the bathroom (I will spare details here). Could you recommend some ginseng supplement with which you had in general good experiences for increased energy and focus?

Comment: Is there some connection to exercise in your question? Please note that general nutrition questions are considered off-topic according to the [faq]. I suggest editing your question to try and make it on-topic if you can. Also note that asking for recommendations and polling aren't typically very constructive questions. You'll end up with a wide range of answers. It would be better to ask something more objective about what it is you actually want.

Comment: Purchase recommendations are not in scope for the site.